# Initialize variable after ajax callback

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm looking for a way to initialize a var after an ajax call. The problem is that the ajax call is in an another file.

Here is my code :

file1.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    getKanbans();
});


function getKanbans() {
    var kanbans = RequestSender.getKanbans();
    console.log(kanbans); // print undefined
}
```

RequestSender.js

```
class RequestSender {
    static getKanbans() {
        $.ajax({
            url: './ajax/select_kanbans.php',
            type: 'GET',
            success: RequestSender.initKanbanList
        });
    }

    static initKanbanList(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        var kanbans = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < result.kanbans.length; ++i) {
            var currentKanban = result.kanbans[i];
            kanbans.push(new Kanban(currentKanban['Name'], currentKanban['Status']))
        }
        console.log(kanbans); // correctly displayed
        return kanbans;
    }
}
```

I just use jQuery, all my files are included. I think that the problem come from the fact that ajax is async but I don't know how to fix that.

Comment: Aren't you using some build tool(s) such as webpack or gulp to bundle these files into one? Alternatively, just make sure that you include the ```RequestSender``` file first? Personally I suggest you take some time to learn about tools such as webpack... Easiest solution would be to simply put them both into the same file? Basically do it manually?...

Comment: Yes i included all these files. I think the problem come from the fact that the ajax call is async

Comment: Why have it in a separate file in the first place?

Comment: @MartinBlondel Have you not just tried some simple callback function? ... I mean you're already doing it with ```getKanbans```, all you need to do is pass a function into ```getKanbans```, which can then be passed on to ```initKanbanList```? Or something along those lines? I mean there's many ways to do this...

Comment: It's because my ajax call has to been in an another file (asked from my teacher). The first file is like a Controller, calling a model. Then, with the result of my RequestSender.getKanbans(), I'll call the view and edit the DOM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in your example ajax call started but kanbans still undefined

```
function getKanbans() {
    //ajax call started but kanbans still undefined
    var kanbans = RequestSender.getKanbans();
    console.log(kanbans); // print undefined
}
```

so you should complete execution after ajax call finished you can do that with the help of promises

[for more information Check this](https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/ajax-async-callback-promise-e98f8074ebd7)

```js
    function getKanbans(url) {
        var promiseObj = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("GET", url, true);
            xhr.send();
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
                    if (xhr.status === 200) {
                        console.log("xhr done successfully");
                        var response = xhr.responseText;
                        var responseJson = initKanbanList(response);
                        resolve(responseJson);
                    } else {
                        reject(xhr.status);
                        console.log("xhr failed");
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("xhr processing going on");
                }
            }
            console.log("request sent succesfully");
        });
        return promiseObj;
    }

    function initKanbanList(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);
        var kanbans = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < result.kanbans.length; ++i) {
            var currentKanban = result.kanbans[i];
            kanbans.push(new Kanban(currentKanban['Name'], currentKanban['Status']))
        }
        console.log(kanbans); // correctly displayed
        return kanbans;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        // to call it 
        getKanbans('./ajax/select_kanbans.php').then(function (kanbans) {
            console.log(kanbans);
        }, function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is called modules in javascript. You can implement them using link tags directly. But you are much better served by libraries like [RequireJS](https://requirejs.org/) and others. Then you can do things like:

```
require(['./RequestSender'], function (RequestSender) {
    var rs = new RequestSender();
    ... //whatever
});
```

Here is a good SO question that explains modules well: [How do I include a JavaScript file in another JavaScript file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/950087/how-do-i-include-a-javascript-file-in-another-javascript-file/950146#950146)

Comment: I'm looking for a way to initialize my variable without using any libraries and using MVC